# Advice on electrical socket fixing into wood fibre internal wall insulation

Tags: insulation, uk, socket, fixings

Our house has recently been insulated with Pavatex wood fibre boards, with a finishing coat of lime plaster on top.

I now want to add more electrical sockets. Standard UK style.

Ideally the back boxes should be set into the insulation rather than surface mounted, unless this is required. I am aware this will of course compromise the insulation in those areas... however I am not sure how to fix them.

Screws into the brick will create a thermal bridge. Wide spiral fixings into the insulation I doubt will be strong enough to stand up to people tugging on it when inserting/removing plugs, at least not for long.

Another option is [Fischer Thermax](https://www.fischerfixingsusa.com/en-us/products/fixation-on-etics-insulation/thermax/thermax-8-and-10/thermax-10) fixings, but these are a) too long, at a minimum of 80mm long and b) hugely expensive at around £100 for 20 fixings.

So what are my options?

- Use the Fischer things, have the boxes surface mounted.
- Use normal fixings and hope for the best re. thermal bridging.
- Spiral fixings and hope they last
- ???

Comment: Linked to the screws for those elsewhere in the world. Are you _really_ going to get _so much_ cold coming through ~2 screws per electrical box that you need to worry about it? If you're really going to get that much thermal transfer, then it seems to me that £5 per screw (one-time cost) is going to be worth it in the reduced heating bills long-term.

Comment: Thanks. I doubt it's much, but then I'm no expert. I just don't want to end up with mould growing around the sockets!

Comment: I'd submit that if you're that worried about getting mold growing inside the house because of a screw penetration of an inside wall, you've got far more serious concerns than the screw penetration.

Comment: This is why I'm asking here... from what I read, a small break in the insulation can cause a surprising amount of heat loss. Not enough to increase my heating bill, but possibly enough to cause a cold spot on the wall, meaning condensation behind the socket, meaning mould... As stated I am no expert but was hoping to find them on here for some practical advice :)

Comment: TBH, my house is from the 1890s and is plenty leaky. I have zero concern about a "small break in the insulation" and haven't had any mold problems anywhere. I'll have to bow out of the discussion now and I really don't know an answer about how this might effect a new, well sealed house.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a [dry lining back box](https://www.screwfix.com/p/appleby-2-gang-dry-lining-knockout-box-35mm/36960):

[image]

The yellow tangs are designed to fold out from inside and grip plasterboard from behind.  You don't have a gap to do that, but maybe you could modify them to attach to the sides of the insulation?  Then you wouldn't have a penetration into the back of the box.

Depends how robust the insulation is - the box shouldn't move when somebody pulls a plug out.

Otherwise, is there scope for gluing the box in?  (eg this plastic box with the tangs removed, if a metal box would be a cold bridge)